# Package cannot find and import another package in the same Module

Tags: android, android-studio

In my app, my MainActivity.class does not recognise or see other packages that are in the module and importing them doesn't work, it only imports or can use classes that are inside the package where MainActivity is.

Although outside of it importing is working fine in every other package and class

Problem shown in red
[image: Problem shown in red]

Comment: that "ga" is not your package

Comment: create your package and then try to import, it will not give any error

Comment: create your package inside com.xxx.xx package

Answer (score 0):

You have to define like com.example.alan.ga.GA ----**full path**